# How do I implement a reverse node reference using References?

Tags: 7, nodes

Using the References module (D7 version), implementing a new field in an article content type for node reference was very easy, but now I cannot seem to figure out how to discern the reverse reference. Just as there is a link shown in my article to the node I have selected in the node reference drop down, I am expecting that on the "linked to" article, I should be able to see a link back to the first article. Has anybody done this? My understanding is that it is part of the D7 version of this module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/cer
You can then setup the reference both ways so when you add a reference on the first piece of content CER can add the back reference to the other piece of content. 
Another option is to add a rule which will do this for you but CER is pretty solid when dealing with larger sites.

Comment: thank you. If you have a link to a tutorial on using CER and Entity API, please let me know.

Comment: This is really the only tutorial (http://www.wdtutorials.com/2013/06/10/drupal-7-module-introduction-corresponding-entity-references#.VK2V27iCPCR) out for CER (at least free, buildamodule.com or drupalize.me may have one paid) but the setup is pretty straight forward, and the instructions on the module page should be enough to get it setup. Also check the README for more info.